# Passing / forwarding events to a sub-object in Qt

Tags: qt, events

I'm working on a Qt application and I have a problem with getting mouse events where I want them.

Here's a high-level view of what I have (there are other things going on at each level that dictate the need for the views and scenes):

```
+----------------
| App Window       -- QMainWindow
| +--------------
| | View           -- QGraphicsView   --- Grabbing mouse events here for Mode 1
| | +------------
| | | Scene        -- QGraphicsScene
| | | +----------
| | | | Image      -- QGraphicsPixmap --- Want to grab mouse events here for Mode 2
| | | |
```

In Mode 1, I'm grabbing the event *mousePressEvent* at the *View* level.  In Mode 2, I'd like to grab the mouse events at the *Image* level.  Before I overloaded *mousePressEvent* in the View class I was able to get all events in *Image*.  Now that I'm capturing at *View* I can't get mouse events in Image.  *Image* is private within *Scene* and I don't want to expose it.

There is no inheritance here; each item is an object created by the object above it.

Reading through this question [Qt -- pass events to multiple objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354877/qt-pass-events-to-multiple-objects) makes it seem like I want to capture mouse events at the *Image* level and let them go back up; however, I would still need to create *mousePressEvent* in *View* and I'd be right back where I am.

Is there a way to turn on/off event handling during run-time and make sure they get to the lower levels?  Or is there a way to forward events to a sub-object?

Comment: Look at this article, maybe it will help you:
http://labs.trolltech.com/blogs/2006/05/27/mouse-event-propagation/

Comment: @vnm: good article; it looks like I want the one he mentions in his PS; unfortunately, I didn't find that one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Is there a way to turn on/off event handling during run-time and make sure they get to the lower levels? Or is there a way to forward events to a sub-object?*

There are some possibilities :

1. Use **QGraphicsScene::sendEvent**(...) to send event to items. As the scene() is accessible from any items by the method **scene**(). Maybe it's a solution for you.
2. You can use the static method **QCoreApplication::sendEvent** (...) for doing the same job.
3. Event filter can do the job, see **Events and event filters chapter**.
4. You can use specific install event system of Graphicsview framework (**QGraphicsItem::sceneEventFilter**(...) and **installSceneEventFilter**(...)

At runtime, it's possible to turn off/on mouse event with the method QGraphicsItem::**setAcceptedMouseButtons**(...).

There are many other possibilities...

Hope it helps !

Comment: I've moved my initial grabbing of events from *View* to *Scene*; I'm closer now but still not getting my events at the bottom.  QGraphicsScene::sendEvent() was added in Qt4.6; I'm still on Qt4.5. This might be the time to update. Event filter wasn't be nice to me either; I'm going to give it a new go now that I moved the layer I'm working on.  Thanks for all the great suggestions!  I'll post a follow-up when I nail it.

Comment: These were all good suggestions. In the end, I stayed with Qt4.5 (we have lots of run-time on this right now and don't have a pressing need to update).  To solve this:  Moved mouse press event capture to the Scene and then call QGraphicsScene::mousePressEvent(event); in Scene::mousePressEvent() for cases I wanted the event to continue on to the QGraphicsItem.